# Make ledger in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have tables

t1 (insert client data)

```
  Date       id    idCl nameCl   opening   
1-8-2016     10L   CL-J  Jon        0     
15-8-2016    20L   CL-B  Ben        0   
25-8-2016    15.5L CL-A  Alina      0     
28-8-2016    10L   CL-B  Ben        0
30-8-2016    20L   CL-J  Jon        0
```

t2 (payment received by client)

```
Date       id    idCl nameCl   receive  
1-9-2016     10L   CL-J  Jon      2000 
1-9-2016     10L   CL-J  Jon      1000   
5-9-2016     20L   CL-B  Ben      3000  
10-9-2016    15.5L CL-A  Alina    5000  
12-9-2016    10L   CL-B  Ben      8000  
22-9-2016    20L   CL-J  Jon      2000
```

i want t3 like this

```
Date       id   idCl nameCl    opening   dr     closing
1-9-2016     10L   CL-J  Jon        0      2000     2000
22-9-2016    20L   CL-J  Jon       2000    1000     3000
1-9-2016     10L   CL-J  Jon       3000    2000     5000  
5-9-2016     20L   CL-B  Ben        0      3000     3000
12-9-2016    10L   CL-B  Ben       3000    8000    11000
10-9-2016    15.5L CL-A  Alina      0      5000     5000
```

the main part is how to make the closing balance to opening balance of client on every transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a two-part solution.
First part (after the initial mcve-makig) is a minimal query to get close to your desired output (except for the weird ordering of 22nd September; 12th before 10th is because of sorting by idCl with higher priority).
Second part spends quite some effort to sort by date which is formatted accordingly.

```
-- make my mcve
-- (including unused table t1, as a nicety to others wanting to answer)
drop table if exists t1 ;
create table t1 (Date date, id varchar(10), idCl varchar(10), nameCl varchar(30), opening int);
drop table if exists t2;
create table t2 (Date date, id varchar(10), idCl varchar(10), nameCl varchar(30), receive int);

insert into t1 values ('1-8-2016',  '10L',   'CL-J',  'Jon', 0); 
insert into t1 values ('15-8-2016', '20L',   'CL-B',  'Ben', 0); 
insert into t1 values ('25-8-2016', '15.5L', 'CL-A',  'Alina', 0); 
insert into t1 values ('28-8-2016', '10L',   'CL-B',  'Ben', 0); 
insert into t1 values ('30-8-2016', '20L',   'CL-J',  'Jon', 0); 

insert into t2 values ('1-9-2016',  '10L',   'CL-J',  'Jon',   2000); 
insert into t2 values ('1-9-2016',  '10L',   'CL-J',  'Jon',   1000); 
insert into t2 values ('5-9-2016',  '20L',   'CL-B',  'Ben',   3000); 
insert into t2 values ('10-9-2016', '15.5L', 'CL-A',  'Alina', 5000); 
insert into t2 values ('12-9-2016', '10L',   'CL-B',  'Ben',   8000); 
insert into t2 values ('22-9-2016', '20L',   'CL-J',  'Jon',   2000); 


.headers off
select '-- simple query, not sorting by date';
.headers on
-- making pretty
.mode column
select 
    a.date,
    a.id, a.idCl, a.nameCL,
    sum(b.receive)-a.receive as opening,
    a.receive               as dr,
    sum(b.receive)          as closing
from t2 as a inner join t2 as b using (idCl)
where    a.rowid >= b.rowid
group by a.rowid 
order by a.idCl DESC
;

-- preparing the use of date for sorting
drop table if exists moneys;
create table moneys (Date date, id varchar(10), idCl varchar(10), nameCl varchar(30), amount int);
insert into moneys select 
    date(       substr(date,-4,4)
         ||'-'||substr('0'||replace(substr(date, instr(date, '-'), 3),'-', ''),-2,2)
         ||'-'||substr('0'||replace(substr(date, 1,2),'-',''),-2,2)
    ),
    id,
    idCl,
    nameCl,
    receive
from t2;

.headers off
select '';
select '-- advanced query, sorting by correct date';
.headers on
select 
    a.date, a.id, a.idCl, a.nameCL,
    sum(b.amount)-a.amount as opening,
    a.amount               as dr,
    sum(b.amount)          as closing
from moneys as a inner join moneys as b using (idCl)
where    a.rowid >= b.rowid
group by a.rowid
order by a.idCl DESC , a.date
;
```

Output:

```
-- simple query, not sorting by date
Date        id          idCl        nameCl      opening     dr          closing
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1-9-2016    10L         CL-J        Jon         0           2000        2000
1-9-2016    10L         CL-J        Jon         2000        1000        3000
22-9-2016   20L         CL-J        Jon         3000        2000        5000
5-9-2016    20L         CL-B        Ben         0           3000        3000
12-9-2016   10L         CL-B        Ben         3000        8000        11000
10-9-2016   15.5L       CL-A        Alina       0           5000        5000

-- advanced query, sorting by correct date
Date        id          idCl        nameCl      opening     dr          closing
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2016-09-01  10L         CL-J        Jon         0           2000        2000
2016-09-01  10L         CL-J        Jon         2000        1000        3000
2016-09-22  20L         CL-J        Jon         3000        2000        5000
2016-09-05  20L         CL-B        Ben         0           3000        3000
2016-09-12  10L         CL-B        Ben         3000        8000        11000
2016-09-10  15.5L       CL-A        Alina       0           5000        5000
```

Notes:
1) The second query order chronologically for the output itself and for the sorting of lines for making the opening sum.
2) The whole table t1 is not used. Should you for example only want to process entries which match an existing account, then filter before inserting into the intermediate table "moneys" or the t2-table entries to be used.
3) The "id" (in contrast to the "idCL") do not have a visible influence, matching your desired output, where for example Ben totals to 11000. Maybe you want the total total over all "id"s. (At first I processed id separatly, thinking they are different accounts, because they are separatly opened in t1.)